# What is "Argument Visibility" and “INFL“ in Case Theory?

Tags: syntax, cases, generative-grammar, minimalism, government-and-binding

I didn't know much about case theory. Can anyone help me explain the meaning of "argument visibility" in a way that is easy to understand?
What's more, does the "INFL" mean "inflectional" in case theory? I was confused.